# How to make LaunchedEffect run once and never again?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose

I know that `LaunchedEffect(key)` is executed when composition starts, and is also cancelled and re-executed again when the `key` changes. However, I want it to be executed only once and never again, I am using the following workaround but I feel like I am missing something:

```kotlin
if (!launchedBefore) {
   LaunchedEffect(null) {
      //stuff

      launchedBefore = true
   }
}
```

The code above works just fine. But it feels like a stretched workaround while something much simpler can be done. Am I misunderstanding how LaunchedEffect fully works?

I tried using `null` and `Unit` as keys cuz they never changed, but the code is executed every time a composition takes place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`LaunchedEffect(Unit)` should execute only once when the composition starts. The only time it would get re-executed during recomposition is if it gets removed from the view tree during one of the previous recompositions. An example would be if you have it within a condition whose value changes at some point (in an `if` block, `when` block or any other conditional statement).

I would assume that the problem with recomposing lies in the other part of the code that is not shown in your snippet. Check if the `LaunchedEffect` is nested in a conditional block that might cause it to get executed after a recomposition.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in the `LaunchEffect` or its `key` parameter, but in the upper composable. The upper composable is getting recomposed. Probably you should display more details how the `LaunchEffect` is called and calling sites.

Recomposition looks up for nearest composable that could have been affected by the change.

Answer (score 1):

I usually pass a longer-living variable for the key, something like `ViewModel`. It will only executed when the ViewModel is being initialized. Or using remembered saveable boolean may do the trick.

```
val bool = rememberSaveable { true }

LaunchedEffect(key1 = bool) {
    // do something
}
```